# How to pass the selected value of radio button using JavaScript from popup window to parent window?

Tags: javascript

I have made a form , which takes input value from a pop up window input field.
I am success to pass value of input type "text " value from child window to parent window, but I am facing problem to pass radio button  value from child window to parent window. Please help me to pass radio button value

```
parent.html

<html> 
<script language="javascript"> 
function openWindow() { 
  window.open("target.html","_blank","height=200,width=400, status=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no"); 
} 
</script> 
<body> 
<form > 
<input id=text1 type=text> 
<input id=text2 type=text> 
<input id=text3 type=text> 

<input type=button onClick="javascript:openWindow()" value="Open window.."> 

</form> 

</body> 
</html>


target.html

<html> 
<body> 

<script>
  function changeParent(){
      var userGrade = document.getElementById('grade');
      //var radios = document.getElementById("level");
      var userLevel= document.getElementById('school');

    window.opener.document.getElementById('text1').value=userGrade.value;

  var rates = document.getElementById('level');
var radio_value;
for(var i = 0; i < rates.length; i++){
    if(rates[i].checked){
        radio_value = rates[i].value;
            window.opener.document.getElementById('text2').value=radio_value.value; 
    }
}   
  window.close();
  }
</script>

<form> 
<input type="text" id="grade" /><br/>


<INPUT TYPE="radio" id="level"  value="level1">level 1

<INPUT TYPE="radio" id="level"  value="level2">level 2 <br/>   

<br/>  

<button onClick="javascript:changeParent()"  >Submit</button>

</form> 

</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, whether the sending process is correct, but as you can see from the jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bBZFG/ , you are addressing the radio elements incorrectly.
Also, the line `window.opener.document.getElementById('text2').value=radio_value.value;` 
is incorrect, since in this scope, the 
`radio_value` 
variable already is the value.

Answer (score 0):

use the following code to get value

```
window.opener.document.getElementById('text2').value=document.form.level.value;
```

after that

```
windows.close();
```